# Is it possible to connect to a server from a local file (not sent to server)?

Tags: server, socket.io, connection, client, local

in my Web-App I want to use a websocket connecting an html file in my app and the server. (using socket.io)

Is it possible to initiate the socket-connection as soon as I open the file locally( eg. file:///../../file.htm) and not on server side: http://localhost/?

How is that possible in a simple example like the following?

client:

```
  var socket = io(); 
  socket.on('connect', function () { 
  socket.emit('a', 'b', function (data) {
  console.log(data); 
  });
});
```

server:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('socket connected');

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('socket disconnected');
});
});
http.listen(80, (ff) =>
console.log('Example app listening on port 80!'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most basic socket.io server:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });
});

console.log('socket.io server started at port 3000');
```

and the html client you can open as file:///client.html in your browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Testing socket.io</h1>
    <h3 id="socket">waiting...</h3>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            document.getElementById("socket").innerHTML = "socket connected";
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            document.getElementById("socket").innerHTML = "socket disconnected";
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's been the missing piece: defining the server adress from both sides.